# Casting types in python __init__

Tags: python, oop, instantiation

I have a python class where one of the attributes should be a Decimal. Is there any potential issue with casting within the **init** method (example a) or is it simply a design choice? Is there a reason to prefer a cast in the calling code instead (example b)?

Example a

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value: int | str | float):
        self.value = Decimal(value)

x = MyClass(1)
y = MyClass('1')
z = MyClass(1.0)
```

Example b

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value: Decimal):
        self.value = value

x = MyClass(Decimal(1))
y = MyClass(Decimal('1'))
z = MyClass(Decimal(1.0))
```

Comment: I'd use a _class method_, e.g. `MyClass.from_input(...)`. Consumers can still do `MyClass(Decimal(...))` if they really want to.

Comment: Is this more a question of typing and signatures or are you asking about guarding that your parameter is actually a decimal in the event that is required?

Comment: Guarding really, because it will cause issues down the line if it's not a Decimal and casting it here will fix it. I just wondered if there was something I hadn't foreseen in doing this way - whether it was a bit code smelly.

Answer (score 0):

If your `MyClass` always internally wants to deal with decimals, do the casting in the constructor, that's fine (and better that way since the user of the class doesn't need to deal with it).

Comment: The counter argument is how do you handle the situation where the value passed (str) cannot be converted to Decimal?

Comment: @DarkKnight The constructor will raise an exception. That'd be the case even if you did `MyClass(Decimal("foople"))`.

Comment: Thank you. I know that. My point is that that may not be a great design choice. Maybe it's a personal thing by I find the notion of \_\_init__ being able to raise an Exception anathema

Comment: In the case of MyClass(Decimal("foople")) the exception is not raised within \_\_init__ and that is precisely my point

Comment: @DarkKnight It doesn't seem to make much of a difference to me here – they'd be raised in the same statement (being the smallest unit of something you could wrap in a `try:except:`) anyway. Having the user have to cast will inevitably lead to someone passing in an integer, and e.g. something later in `MyClass` doing `self.value.quantize` or whatnot will fail, and it's better to fail fast.

Comment: Why is an exception in a constructor anathema? Isn't `Decimal("foople")` raising an exception in Decimal's constructor?